# Using backreference in REGEXP by SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, regex, unicode

I´m struggling to query repeated words separated by a space for instance *abc* *abc* or *def* *def*

The condition of the select statement looks like the following:

```
WHERE `Text` REGEXP '[:space:]?([^[:space:]]+)[:space:]\1';
```

But I did not receive any results! I appreciate any contributions!

**HINT:** Since I'm dealing with the arabic language I can't use \w to match a word.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? They each support their own flavor of regex

Comment: @Error_2646 mySQLWorkbench

Comment: MySQL regular expressions don't support back-references.

Comment: @Barmar Any references?

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax) doesn't include them.

Comment: And if it did support them, you need to escape the backslash: `\\1`

Comment: Cf. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29590 MySQL has never supported backreferences.

Comment: @BillKarwin, this is true for version 5.7 and below, but what about version 8? https://dbfiddle.uk/3qwsc6hh

Comment: Good catch. They should mark that feature request closed as of 8.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8, you need to double any backslash used for special purposes, such as `\\1`.  Then your example works.

Things were different in older versions.  (It sounds like the 8.0 docs are incomplete.)

Comment: It tired it, but does not work!